# Is there music player that supports both AAC and MIDI files on Android 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, music-player

Update from 2.1 to 2.3 broken playing from aac files in most players.

The only music player that is more or less usable is PowerAMP (and also video players like MoboPlayer and MX Player). But it won't play midi files.

The only player that can play both aac and mid files I tried is MoboPlayer. But it is video player (so no useful widget/play queue).

```
Player:   Support AAC on 2.3   Support mid    have widget
PowerAMP          +                  -            +
Most players      -                  +            -
MoboPlayer        +                  +            -

I want            +                  +            +
```

How to fix aac in android 2.3 in SE Xperia X10? Alternatively, is there a player that can play both aac and mid files and have widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround found: wrap all aac files into matroska containers and usual music players start recognising them.

```
mkvmerge some_music.aac -o some_music.mka
```

Comment: Looks like Android 4.4 doesn't like Matroska files (especially ones that doesn't contain video track). Need `m4a` instead of `mkv` for it.